# Windows 11: Windows intelligence update errors with code 0x00000000

Tags: windows-update, windows-11

I had posted this on stack overflow but it was suggested here is a better place for this question.

I've been having issues with updating Windows for the past couple of months. At the point where I reinstalled Windows 11 from a new ISO about a week ago.

My recent issue is, there's a "Windows intelligence update" which I'm trying to install through settings. When I click "update all ran restart" it stays at "downloading - 0%"

After a while it fails with "install error - 0x00000000" which when searching provides me with no information.

When searching for this and some of the other messages, I have tried:

- [Followed these steps to reinstall some core packages](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/0x00000000-error-code-in-windows-store-windows-10/afc425c9-2c98-459e-a9ea-1974fa21d76a)
- checking registry for
- running `DSIM` and `SFC`
- clearing windows update cache
- verifying core DLLs

I'm struggling to find any other resources for resolving this error for Windows updates.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No errors here with Windows 11 Production (2 machines) or Windows 11 Insider.  Do you have legacy software installed?  Have you updated all drivers including BIOS?

Comment: i did have an insider build installed, which i hoped to unenroll from in the next major update. however that was impossible due to another error with windows update with different error code. I reinstalled with windows 11 version: 22H2, build: 22621.525

Comment: Check your software closely and remember that Insider Builds (I have one) are not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions. It turns out the right way to fix my issue was rebooting my router.

There were some other issues happening on my network which I should have done this for anyway, but it's resolved itself now.

Again, thanks for the help. I hope this resolves others issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Windows 11 *should* have fixed the issue, if nothing else did. However:

1. If you have any other anti-malware suite than *Windows Defender* installed, that might block the Intelligence Update, part of *Defender*. If so, do not try to run two full-time anti-malware suites at the same time.
2. Try the [Windows Update Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-troubleshooter-19bc41ca-ad72-ae67-af3c-89ce169755dd#WindowsVersion=Windows_11).
3. You can also update *Defender* from the *Virus & threat protection* CPL, which I found worked in one case where general Windows  updates failed.

[image: Update Defender]

4. Finally, you state you used "DSIM and SFC" [sic]. Did you *DISM* use it to [reset updates to current baseline](https://msft.today/dism-exe-online-cleanup-image-startcomponentcleanup/) to clear the queue? That *might* help.

Comment: i reinstalled windows from a current ISO from the Microsoft website. Which i thought would have fixed this as well.

I don't have any other antivirus software installed, and the virus and threat updates says the same.

i did run dsim, but with different flags i'll run through the article you sent.